# Get raml2html to work on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nodejs

I'd like to be able to execute `raml2html` to generate documentation for some APIs that are specified using RAML.  I have installed `raml2html` using the `nodejs` package manager via

```
$> sudo npm i -g raml2html
```

But executing it fails:

```
$> raml2html interface.raml 
[Error: AssertionError: urllib-sync need node version 0.11.13+]
```

I've tried doing an

```
$> sudo apt-get update
```

to update the libraries.  The only packages returned from `apt-cache search urllib` are python libraries, so I don't think that they are relevant.

What do I need to install/upgrade in order to get `raml2html` to work?

`node` is the up to date version `v0.10.25`

Comment: Can you try `node -v` and tell us the version of your Node.js?

Comment: It looks like your `node` is not the version that `urllib-sync` needs.

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS by running the following:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo bash -
sudo npm i -g raml2html
```

See https://github.com/nodejs/LTS/ for more information on the different NodeJS versions.